# What component can I use for this purpose in android?

Tags: android, components

I want this kind of componet:
1.It can run all the times until app terminates.
2.It must run background.
3.It must be sigleton.
4.It can communicate with all activities
So what kind of componet can I use? Waht about background activity ?

Comment: Service is what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried, and it must be started by an activity. I just want it start before all activity.

Comment: Have all of your activities start it first thing... the first one will actually start it, the others will just cause its use count to increase.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can use a Service.

Here is the link to Android Developers:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Ok, but I find it must be started by an activity.In fact I want it start firstly.

Comment: You can do it in the start of the onCreate of your main activity... Or you intent to use this service to multiple Applications?

Comment: :I have tried start service in the onCreate function of activity.But I found that variables in service is not avaliable until service is constructed successfully.However service constructing cost time and I want to use this variables in onCreate function in activity.So it doesn't work well.

Comment: If your variables are primitive types you can also use Shared Preferences... But normally this is used to application settings... This is the android developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: This variables are dynamical got from webserver. Such as user information. I tried an method that is use cookie.But I think get information real-time is much more better.

Answer (score 0):

Its called services. [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) you can find the best tutorial